# BasicNameValuePair not working with @ (at symbol) in value - Trying to create an HTTP POST request in Android

Tags: android, apache, http

I am trying to create an HTTP POST request in android where I pass "username" and "password" as POST variables.

I have code that works under most circumstances.  However when the password contains the "@" symbol it no longer works.

Here is my code

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "the_username"));
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "the_password"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData, HTTP.UTF_8));
    
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

If "the_password" contains an @, such as "the_password@" then I'm not sure what the POST sends over the wire, but I get an error from the server.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) indicates that certain special characters have to be escaped, but I'm not what API call to use to do that - and I have had no luck trying to manually escape the characters in my hard coded string.

Further more if I replace the following line:

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

with

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("username=the_username&password=the_password@", HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Then everything works - but this isn't a great solution because username and password are user entered and I'm unsure as to how that will work if they pass in a string with ampersand (&) or equals(=) in it

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your server correctly handles URL-escaped parameters?

If I run this:

```
List<NameValuePair> postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "the_username"));
postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "the_password@"));

String urlencoform = EntityUtils.toString(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData, HTTP.UTF_8));
String directstring = EntityUtils.toString(new StringEntity("username=the_username&password=the_password@", HTTP.UTF_8));
```

I get:

```
urlencoform = "username=the_username&password=the_password%40"
directstring = "username=the_username&password=the_password@"
```

So this means it "works" with your server if you're sending **unencoded** parameters. This can't be good.

Any change to check what the server is receiving and how it does/does not handle it?

Comment: Philipp - Thank you so much for your suggestion.  I never even thought that the issue might be on the server end.  I am accessing a public API of a larger company and I just took it for granted that everything on their end would be set up correctly.  I am going to try and get in contact with them and see what I find out.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: haven't gotten a definitive answer from the API provider yet - but given the evidence and I'm going to select this answer as I do think the problem is not with my Java code, but with the server implementation that processes the API request

Comment: This "@" == %40 , and  EntityUtils and UrlEncodedFormEntity(value,"UTF-8") not work ////////// 2015